# how to use string data for svm (smo) in weka

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka

I have an arff file containing some sentences (Persian language) and a word in front of each sentence which shows its class in @data part. I need to use smo for classification. The questions:

1) Is it necessary to change the sentences to vectors ?

2) I selected "string to word vector", but the smo is inactive and still doesn't work. (and of course other algorithms like naive bayes).

How can I use this text data with smo ?

[image]

The above picture is a very small sample file.

file sample:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohpyortve8jbwhe/shoor.arff?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need apply "string to word vector" filter. After, on classify tab, you need to change the target class to "(Nom) class". This is enought to enable the naive bayes and SVM algorithms. I downloaded the dataset, and it worked well.

You can follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlVJ2_N_Olo

Hope it can help you

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import arff
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data=list(arff.load('shoor.arff'))

text=[]
label=[]
for r in data:
    if (len(r)>1):
        text.append(r[0])
        label.append(r[1])
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(text)
features = (tfidf * tfidf.T).A


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, label, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

1.0

Comment: I solved the problem. Now it returns the answer. But when I use "string to word vector", Because the sentences are Persian, the alphabets change to the shapes in the picture above. Does weka recognizes these shapes as real words in Persian? I mean does it have any influence on the answer?

Comment: How can I change these shapes to real words in Persian?

Comment: Hi, my guess is yes. But weka is a "black box", so it is bit difficult to test it. How about implement a simple Python and scipy to do it? I can have a code in my stuffs. If you want, I can share the code with you ;)

Comment: yes. thank you. I need it. can you put it on drop box please.